# Mysql Count, If , Else

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, count

```
    {
    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `membership` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = :id");
    $count = $odb->num_rows;
    $SQL -> execute(array(':id' => $_SESSION['ID']));
    if ($count > 0){
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The data must be retrieved from the database of User. And if the value of membership is 0, then get Return False deployed. If not, return True. But the script does not work ... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `does not work` is never a good problem description. How is the result you're currently getting different from what you want? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `$count = $odb->num_rows;` below `$SQL -> execute(array(':id' => $_SESSION['ID']));`